# Accessing saga repository

Tags: masstransit, saga

I have the need to access the saga repository from within a consumer to read the current status of the saga correlated to the message being consumed.

**Scenario:**
I have an external service, when this service consumes an event coming from the saga I want to see if the saga is still in the correct state because if meanwhile the saga changed its state the consumer must skip the event.

**How:** I surely could query the saga repository implementation chosen by using its the native framework, but I would like to use an abstraction, an interface, to load the saga state from within the consumer, in order to be able to switch to a different repository implementation in the future.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the saga initiated the command, sending it to the consumer, why would the consumer need to check the saga's state? Is there a long delay between the time the command is sent and the consumer is able to process it?

The type of check you are asking about sort of goes against what a system would generally do when processing commands. If you do need to do this type of check, I'd actually suggest a request/response interaction using the request client to which the saga would respond if the command is still *valid*. That way, the logic (and locking) of the saga repository remains under the saga's control.

> If needed, a separate endpoint could be used for that request to ensure it isn't backed up behind other messages targeting the saga. If that is desired, post a comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I really need that check, in my scenario the saga maintains a very long and time consuming distributed transaction where the tasks must be processed concurrently in order to speed up the process. Tasks are scheduled at beginning, in case of a fail of a single activity the remaining pending commands must be skipped.

Comment: Have you checked routing slips? I think they the framework already implemented what you are building https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/routing-slip